# How can I install Eclipse 4?

Tags: software-center, eclipse

I am current on Ubuntu 12.04. and the eclipse available through the software center is version 3.7. But eclipse 4 is already out there for windows.

When will eclipse 4 be available for Ubuntu, can I install it now?